# Scope name error when converting pretrained model from pytorch to keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pytorch, onnx

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) /tmp/ipykernel_2113989/1063976035.py in 
> 11
> 12 # we should specify shape of the input tensor
> ---> 13 k_model = pytorch_to_keras(model, input_var, [(3, 224, 224,)], verbose=True)
> 14 #k_model = pytorch_to_keras(model, input_var, [(3, None, None,)], verbose=True)
> 15
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch2keras/converter.py
> in pytorch_to_keras(model, args, input_shapes, change_ordering,
> verbose, name_policy, use_optimizer, do_constant_folding)
> 82     k_model = onnx_to_keras(onnx_model=onnx_model, input_names=input_names,
> 83                             input_shapes=input_shapes, name_policy=name_policy,
> ---> 84                             verbose=verbose, change_ordering=change_ordering)
> 85
> 86     return k_model
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/onnx2keras/converter.py
> in onnx_to_keras(onnx_model, input_names, input_shapes, name_policy,
> verbose, change_ordering)
> 179             lambda_funcs,
> 180             node_name,
> --> 181             keras_names
> 182         )
> 183         if isinstance(keras_names, list):
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/onnx2keras/operation_layers.py
> in convert_clip(node, params, layers, lambda_func, node_name,
> keras_name)
> 39         lambda_func[keras_name] = target_layer
> 40
> ---> 41     layers[node_name] = layer(input_0)
> 42
> 43
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py
> in **call**(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
> 819                                               self.name)
> 820         graph = backend.get_graph()
> --> 821         with graph.as_default(), backend.name_scope(self._name_scope()):
> 822           # Build layer if applicable (if the `build` method has been
> 823           # overridden).
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py
> in **enter**(self)    6442     else:    6443       scope =
> get_default_graph().name_scope(self._name)
> -> 6444       scope_name = scope.**enter**()    6445       self._exit_fns.append(scope.**exit**)    6446     return scope_name
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py in **enter**(self)
> 110         del self.args, self.kwds, self.func
> 111         try:
> --> 112             return next(self.gen)
> 113         except StopIteration:
> 114             raise RuntimeError("generator didn't yield") from None
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py
> in name_scope(self, name)    4127         # op name regex, which
> constrains the initial character.    4128         if not
> _VALID_OP_NAME_REGEX.match(name):
> -> 4129           raise ValueError("'%s' is not a valid scope name" % name)    4130     old_stack = self._name_stack    4131     if not
> name:  # Both for name=None and name="" we re-set to empty scope.
>
> ValueError: 'onnx::Conv_369' is not a valid scope name

I am trying to convert pytorch pretrained model to keras via pytorch2keras (https://github.com/gmalivenko/pytorch2keras).

I had tried to install older version of Onnx (1.8.1) and tried to install Onnx from main branch (https://github.com/onnx/onnx).

However, I still face the error. May I know how to solve it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting name_policy='renumerate' or name_policy='short' for onnx_2_keras.

Answer (score 0):

I went though the same problem. In my case I had created a custom CNN with **PyTorch** and when converting it to **Keras** model I got the scope name violation. setting the option **name_policy='renumerate'** did the trick for me.